# How can a lightsaber block another lightsaber if the blade is made of light?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, weapon, physics

According to *Star Wars* canon, the blade of a lightsaber is a highly concentrated beam of light or energy. However, in real-world physics - when two light beams or even laser beams pass through each other, they interfere locally and continue their way. This means that two colliding lightsaber blades should be "transparent" to each other and thus blocking a lightsaber blade with another would be impossible. A similar thing happens if the lightsaber's blade is made of hot plasma. So how does *Star Wars* explain the non-physical fact that a lightsaber blocks another lightsaber as if the blades were solid objects?

Comment: Mumble, mumble, Force, mumble.

Comment: @JRE - Nope: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r1O8.png